# Selenium UI Test issue

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I am having an javascript error while selenium automated UI test is running on build server. The error message is

```
JavaScript error: chrome://mozapps/content/plugins/pluginProblem.xml, line 83: Permission denied to access property 'dispatchEvent'
```

locally if I run UI test, I can not see that error even. It happens only during continuous integration build. Selenium test does not execute any JavaScript itself. We are using c#,  FF 26.0 and Selenium WebDriver 2.41.0.0

I have been stuck for days, if anybody could help me resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details - What language are you using? What browser and version? Selenium version?

Comment: Is your selenium test executing any JavaScript itself, or is this purely as a result of interacting with the page? Presumably you don't see any errors when using the page manually?

Comment: locally if I run UI test, I can not see that error even. It happens only during continuous integration build. We are using c#,  FF 26.0 and Selenium WebDriver 2.41.0.0

Comment: if you run your keyevents on firebug do you get the error too?

Comment: I can not use firebug because automated UI test keep opening and closing many pages as each test required. As I said, if I run manually, I can not see any javascript error.